# embedding a k-linear category in an additive category

Tags: category-theory

I am reading an article and it is written there: 
If $A$ is a $k$-linear category (possibly without direct sums) we can embed it in the
additive category $A \times \mathbb{N}$, where a morphism $(x,m) \mapsto (y, n)$ is an $n \times m$ matrix
with entries in $A(x, y) = Hom_A(x, y)$. Of course if $A$ is additive then $A \approx A \times \mathbb{N}$. Could anyone explain it? Why is it additive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you haven't got the objects quite right. A better description of the objects of the free additive category $\oplus A$ over $A$ is: $n$-tuples of objects $x = (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n})$ of $A$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now a morphism in
$\text{Hom}\,(x,y)$ is a matrix $(f_{ij})$, where $f_{ij} \in \text{Hom}_A\,(x_{j},y_{i})$ and composition is given by the familiar formula for matrix multiplication.

Can you see why *this* category is additive?

Also show that it deserves its name and think about the following:

1. every additive functor $F: A \to B$ to an additive category $B$ extends uniquely to an additive functor $\oplus F : \oplus A \to B$.
2. If $A$ is already additive then $A$ and $\oplus A$ are equivalent.
3. What is the free $k$-linear category over $A$?